# Qt Android - Can't run/build Android using Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm trying to run my Qt app for Android.But when I try to run it I get the following error.

```
Android build SDK not defined. Check Android settings.
Error while building/deploying project Paypal-mobile (kit: Android for 
armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.9.1 for Android armv7))
When executing step "Build Android APK"
```

I'm sure I have JDK, SDK and NDK in the right place.[image]

**Edit:** I just noticed that my Android SDK build is empty. Any ideas?